# How come my MongoDB query doesn't work?

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, database

I'm using pymongo: http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.9%2B/index.html

```
for post in db.datasets.find({"set":"flickr"}).sort("num_favs","-1"):
    ...
```

How come I can't sort this? I'd like it sorted descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

second item in each key pair must be ASCENDING, DESCENDING, or GEO2D

Comment: I did this, but it still doesn't work. sort("num_favs","ASCENDING").  TypeError at /
second item in each key pair must be ASCENDING, DESCENDING, or GEO2D

Comment: @TIMEX: `pymongo.ASCENDING` not `"ASCENDING"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.sort("num_favs",-1)` instead of `,"-1"`.